# Linux changing serial parity without affecting DTR line

Tags: linux, serial-port, termios

I am trying change an open serial port on Linux from 8E1 to 8N1 without changing the DTR flow control line.  DTR is connected to the Reset pin of an STM32 and RTS is connected to Boot0 allowing me to run the built in bootloader and upload and run code in RAM.  The problem is the boot loader is 8E1 and the upload code is 8N1.  The code snipit I am using to change the parity is:

```
tcgetattr(fd, &settings);
settings.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
settings.c_iflag &= ~INPCK;
tcsetattr(fd, TCSADRAIN, &settings);
```

However this cause the DTR line to drop resetting the STM32.  When I want to change the DTR line I am using ioctl(fd, TIOCMSET, &status), I assume tcsetattr() should have no effect on DTR.  As a test I tried just the tcgetattr() and tcsetattr() calls without changing any data and it still fails.

Am I overlooking something or is this likely to be a driver issue that I can't code around in a normal program?

Comment: Do you `close(2)` the driver somewhere in the program? Is it the only program that has the driver open?  DTR switch is normally associated to first `open(2)`/last `close(2)` for the driver.  This normally forces line hangup when a modem (the device RS-232C was initially made to drive) is connected to the line.  Try to maintain the line open in your program while doing those operations (so it doesn't receive a close from the system, making DTR to fail) Put a `sleep(100000);` after the code and control it from another program.

Comment: Good question.  I already suspected that is what happens so what I have been doing is adding a terminal program to the stm32flash program purely so I would not have to close the serial device.  Hence the need to change the parity.